# several executions in on db transaction

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I am trying to insert values in a sqlite database.
If I limit the the executions to only one execution with the line

```
if (i==0)
```

as in the example, the values get inserted in the database.
However, if I drop the limiting line, NONE gets inserted, instead of all as I would expect.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "mydb"});

db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable(id integer primary key, content text)');
});

   db.transaction(function(tx) {
     for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
        val = values[i];
        // val = (1,'Value 1'), (2, 'Value 2');
        if (i==0)
            tx.executeSql("insert into mytable values "+val);

    }

});
```

}

what can I do?

Comment: What are the values of `values[0]` and `values[1]`?

Comment: values[0] = "(1,'Value 1')"; values[1]="(2, 'Value 2')";

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
  The last Element of values was corrupted, so the transaction as a whole failed.